# Cannot display post of Blogger with custom template code

Tags: templates, xhtml, blogger

I make this code:

```
<b:widget id='Blog1' type='Blog' locked='true'>
        <b:includable id='wrap' var='post'>
                <b:loop var='post' values='data:posts'>
                        <b:include name='post' data='post'/>
                </b:loop>
        </b:includable>

        <b:includable id='post' var='post'>
                <a expr:href='data:post.url'><h3><data:post.title/></h3></a>
                <p><data:post.author/></p>
                <section><data:post.body/></section>
        </b:includable>
</b:widget>
```

Here is the problem, it cannot display the post which is title, author name, body. I don't understand why, I've done everything like the "Help page" of Blogger said but it is not working. I also try to use original code of old template (which still working well) but it just have a same fate with my code when I paste it into my new template, not working.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem.
This happens because in a recent update Blogger automatically saves post.body elements in a specific order and does not let you to alter it.
Still trying to find a workaround myself.